# vba add powerpoint table style from vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I try to apply a powerpoint table style from vba excel but i had an issue, someone can help to try how apply a style in table object ?

My macro work fine expect the style part ....

this code go to error 400 -- execution error --> Method 'table' of the object 'Shape' has failed

```
Set otbl = PPT_Shape.Table
```

This is a sample of my code here below

```
Sub ExcelRangeToPowerPoint()
'PURPOSE: Copy/Paste An Excel Range Into a New PowerPoint Presentation

Dim rng As Range
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object
Dim sPath As String
Dim project As String
Dim otbl As TableObject
'Set Title
project = Feuil1.Cells("2", "C")
'Set the template
sPath = "C:\Users\E049XXXX\OneDrive - XXX\XXX\"
'Copy Range from Excel
  Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:N34")
'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
  On Error Resume Next  
    'Is PowerPoint already opened?
      Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")   
    'Clear the error between errors
      Err.Clear
    'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
      If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
    
    'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
        Exit Sub
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
'Create a New Presentation
  Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add
  

'Add a slide to the Presentation
  Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly
  
'Add a slide to the Presentation
  PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.ApplyTemplate "C:\Users\E049XXXX\OneDrive - XXXX\Documents\XXXXX.thmx"

'Copy Excel Range
  rng.Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
  mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=0  '0 = ppPasteDefault
  Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
  
    'Set position:
      myShape.Left = 66
      myShape.Top = 152

'Add Title
        Set myTitle = mySlide.Shapes.Title
        myTitle.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = project
'Add style


Set PPT_Shape = myShape
Set otbl = PPT_Shape.Table
With otbl
    .ApplyStyle "{C083E6E3-FA7D-4D7B-A595-EF9225AFEA82}", True
End With

'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
  PowerPointApp.Visible = True
  PowerPointApp.Activate

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you expect us to reconstruct most of your macro to test it. Here's how to create a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Error code 400 could be a dozen different things, what is the exact text of the error message?

Comment: ok, i will do explain better than the fist example

Comment: Assuming you're running this from within Excel, TableObject is, I guess, a valid Excel definition, but once you paste into PPT, the result is a PPT Table object; PPT has no TableObject object type.  Try Dimming otbl as Table instead.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg yes it's true... but the Dimming otbl as Table is not accepted by VBA in Excel....

Comment: @Pierre-Marie Sorry, you're right, of course. Dim it as an Object instead or use early binding, which would let you Dim oTbl as PowerPoint.Table

Comment: @SteveRindsberg it's seems to be the same as Table, PowerPoint.Table is not accepted

Comment: As I mentioned, you'd have to use early binding for this to work. In the VBA editor, use Tools | References to set a reference to the Microsoft PowerPoint object library.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Many thanks, it was already binded... but i find an other to paste with this method '''PowerPointApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")